# Showing "Field is required" error message for is null operator in jqGrid search

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqGrid advanced search.I don't want to search with empty value so I set `required:true` in search rule (`searchrules:{required:true}`) for all field. My problem is i am getting "Field is required" error message, if i select is `null` operator and click find button in find popup.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var grid = $("#list"),
        mydata = [
           {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
           {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"},
           {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}
        ];

    grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: mydata,
        colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
        colModel:[
            {name:'id',index:'id', key: true, width:70, sorttype:"int",searchrules:{required:true}},
            {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date",searchrules:{required:true}},
            {name:'name',index:'name', width:100,searchrules:{required:true}},
            {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float",searchrules:{required:true}},
            {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float",searchrules:{required:true}},
            {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float",searchrules:{required:true}},
            {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false,searchrules:{required:true}}
        ],
        search:true,
        pager:'#pager',
        jsonReader: {cell:""},
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        sortname: 'id',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        height: "100%",
        caption: "Multiple search with local data"
    });
    grid.jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{add:false,edit:false,del:false,search:true,refresh:true},
                {},{},{},{multipleSearch:true, multipleGroup:true, showQuery: true});
});
```

HTML CODE

```html
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that requirement to use `null` operator contradicts the rule `searchrules: {required: true}`. The rule `required: true` means that the data of the search field can't be empty. On the other side `null` operator have no data.

Comment: ok but do you have any solution for this problem?I want to use is null operator too.

Comment: @Rigan: I don't understand why you want to use `required: true` in the case? You should just remove it. Which columns in your grid can be nullable? `note` column? then you should remove `searchrules: {required: true}` for the column.

Comment: All columns(field) can be nullable except Inv No(Id) but I don't want to search column(field) with empty value.So i used `required: true`.